# Efficiently append a string to each file line in unix

Tags: file, unix, append

I have a tab delimited file where I'd like to append the string "chr" before every first field of every line, except the first line which is a header line (and starts with the "#" character).

So for example, the second line is:

```
1       51476   snp_1_51476     T       C       100     PASS
```

And I'd like it to be:

```
chr1       51476   snp_1_51476     T       C       100     PASS
```

What would be an efficient way in unix to achieve this for a file with ~10 million lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR>1 {$1="chr"$1}1' file
```

This appens "chr" to every single line except the first one. Then, `1` triggers the print of every line.

Otherwise, with `sed`:

```
sed '2,$s/^/chr/' file
```

This adds the suffix `chr` to all lines starting from the 2nd one. Adding `-i`, that is `sed -i '2,$s/^/chr/' file` will make the substitution in place.

---

To do it with every file in your current directory, say:

```
for file in *
do
   awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR>1 {$1="chr"$1}1' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
done
```